# Ruby on Rails, Select Users with age range from Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

User.rb

```
# Attributes
# (..)
# birthdate (string)
#  format "mm/yyyy"

def age
  dob = self.birthdate.to_date
  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end
```

In the console:

```
irb(main):002:0> current_user.age
=> 7
```

I'd be able to do the following:

```
age_range = "25-65"
User.where(:age => between age_range)
```

I'm stuck at the point how to get the value from age (class method) into the where call

Comment: This would be much much easier if you stored the birthdate as an actual date.

Comment: When I store users age in a database column, I risk to get bad results for records with outdated age

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that, but if you store birthdate as a date column then it should be straightforward to convert an age range to a birthdate range

Comment: @StefHej What exactly do you mean by an 'outdated age'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: use a date as type for birthdate in the database.

Then you can just use:

`User.where(birthdate: 65.years.ago..25.years.ago)`

If you can't change the birthdate type convert it using SQL (example with PostrgeSQL):

`User.where('to_date(birthdate, 'MM/YYYY') between ? and ?', 65.years.ago, 25.years.ago)`

But you may still have to correct it since you  don't have the exact day and only the month.

Answer (score 0):

With PostgreSQL you can use that Rails scope

```
scope :for_age_range, -> min, max {
  where("date_part('year', age(birthdate)) >= ? AND date_part('year', age(birthdate)) <= ?", min, max)
}
```

`User.for_age_range(18, 24)`